# Accepting Map or JSON in a constructor or method

Tags: solidity, solc

I have a question:

Can a Contract accept a HashMap kind of a data structure or some kind of a JSON structure of the following format in its Constructor?

```
[
{key1 -> {val1, val2, val3}},
{key2 -> {val1, val2, val3}},
{key3 -> {val1, val2, val3}}
]
```

If it can, how to extract these (k, {v}) pairs in the contract and store them in some mapping?

Could someone please show me examples of both?

Thanks.